# Hi, I have a python script to work with excel data using openpyxl ,but after 2500 rows i am getting Memory Error. Can anyone help me on this?

Tags: python, excel, memory, out-of-memory, openpyxl

I have a python script to work with excel data using `openpyxl` ,but after 2500 rows I am getting Memory Error. Can anyone help me on this?

Here I am writing to the excel and simultaneously working on the updated data.

```
import openpyxl
import json,ast,xlrd
loc = "primeline_delivery.xlsx"
shee = openpyxl.load_workbook(loc)
sheet=shee.active
n_col=sheet.max_column
n_col_1=n_col+1
for q in range(1,n_col_1):
    if(sheet.cell(row=1,column=q).value=='source_product_attributes'):
        source=q
for i in range(2,sheet.max_row):
    a=sheet.cell(row=i,column=source).value
    if(a!='[""]'):
        a1=ast.literal_eval(a)
        for j in a1:
            j1=ast.literal_eval(j)
            for k in j1.items():
                print(k)
                for x in range(1,n_col_1):

                    t=0
                    if (sheet.cell(row=1,column=x).value ==k[0]):
                        found = x
                        t=t+1
                        sheet.cell(row=i,column=x).value=str(k[1])
                if(t==0):


                     sheet.cell(row=1,column=n_col_1).value=str(k[0])
                     sheet.cell(row=i,column=n_col_1).value=str(k[1])
                     n_col_1 = n_col_1 + 1
                     print(i)

shee.save('test1.xlsx')
```

The code is working fine but after 2500 rows I am getting a memory error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\sryasz\PycharmProjects\sel\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py",
> line 240, in cell   File
> "C:\Users\sryasz\PycharmProjects\sel\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py",
> line 256, in _get_cell MemoryError

Answer (score 0):

In older and maybe at the current  stable release lof `openpyxl` you could pass `use_iterators=True` to `load_workbook()`. This feature seems to be deprecated thought in the upcoming releases.

Also, optimized modes could help: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/optimized.html - You could try to first copy your original excel file to a tempporary file, open your initial state as read-only, temporary as write-only and then iterate the read-only version but make the updates to write-only one and once you have processed all your data, close both and move the temporary write-only back to the original one.